# EF Core Npgsql 6.0 PostgresSQL "Legacy TimeStamp Behavior" isn't working consistently

Tags: postgresql, datetime, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I have a multitude of EF Core projects, and when I try to add (per [the documentation](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/release-notes/6.0.html?tabs=annotations#timestamp-rationalization-and-improvements)) the

```
AppContext.SetSwitch("Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior", true);
```

(aka "*the switch*") statement to the project, I get inconsistent behavior depending on the project.

When I run the

```
dotnet ef migrations add "test_migration"
```

command, *some* of the projects don't generate the `Alter` statements for the timestamp columns (which is the desired behavior) if the switch is in `Startup.Configure()`, but some do.

In some projects when the switch is in the `ApplicationDbContext.ctor()`, it works as expected - and sometimes not.

To make things MORE interesting, in some projects I can put the switch in the `appsettings.json`, and it works there …but again, sometimes not.

In all projects, the `DbContext` is added to the service collection the same way:

```
services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql()
    .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseNpgsql(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("XXXX"),
            postgresOpts =>
            {
                postgresOpts.SetPostgresVersion(9, 6);              
            });
    });
```

If there is anything else about my code that might influence this outcome I'm not aware of it; I am looking for a way to make this change across all projects that works consistently.

Comment: Do you have a [mre] we can look at?

Comment: No, I don't - I have a dozen projects and despite all having the same setup they're all behaving differently.